# How do I put bootstrap navbar ON hero image

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I am using the Hero Image example code from W3Schools and the Bootstrap Navbar, and they won't connect. Like there's a little space in between filled with background color. StackOverflow wouldnt let me post the code here because it was too long, so here are the links:https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hero_image.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp
https://kalpact.repl.co

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysterious spacing under navbar in Bootstrap 3.3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33924887/mysterious-spacing-under-navbar-in-bootstrap-3-3-5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your navbar has an explicit bottom margin, coming from `navbar.less`:.

```
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: @navbar-margin-bottom;
}
```

Ideally, you should find where "navbar-margin-bottom" is defined and change it to 0.  But... I've searched for that definition and can't seem to find it anywhere.  You may have to just add this to your main stylesheet:

```
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```